# How to jump to next top level loop?

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I have a `for` loop nested in another `for` loop. How can I make it so that when something happens in the inner loop, we exit and jump to the next iteration of the outer loop?

```
u <- 0

for (i in 1:100) {
    u <- u + 1
    j <- 1000
    for (e in 1:30) {
        j <- j - 1
        if (j < 990) {
            # if j is smaller than 990 I hope start next time of i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See: `next` and `break`, but here I would rather have an inner loop like: `for (j in 1000:970) {...}`

Answer (score 18):

@flodel has the correct answer for this, which is to use `break` rather than `next`. Unfortunately, the example in that answer would give the same result whichever control flow construct was used.

I'm adding the following example just to make clear how the behavior of the two constructs differs.

```
## Using `break`
for (i in 1:3) {
   for (j in 3:1) {     ## j is iterated in descending order
      if ((i+j) > 4) {
         break          ## << Only line that differs
      } else {
         cat(sprintf("i=%d, j=%d\n", i, j))
      }}}
# i=1, j=3
# i=1, j=2
# i=1, j=1

## Using `next`
for (i in 1:3) {
   for (j in 3:1) {     ## j is iterated in descending order
      if ((i+j) > 4) {
         next           ## << Only line that differs
      } else {
         cat(sprintf("i=%d, j=%d\n", i, j))
      }}}
# i=1, j=3
# i=1, j=2
# i=1, j=1
# i=2, j=2   ##  << Here is where the results differ
# i=2, j=1   ##
# i=3, j=1   ##
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you want to use `break` so R will stop looping through your inner `for` loop, hence proceed to the next iteration of your outer `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   for (j in 1:10) {
      if ((i+j) > 5) {
         # stop looping over j
         break
      } else {
         # do something
         cat(sprintf("i=%d, j=%d\n", i, j))
      }
   }
}
# i=1, j=1
# i=1, j=2
# i=1, j=3
# i=1, j=4
# i=2, j=1
# i=2, j=2
# i=2, j=3
# i=3, j=1
# i=3, j=2
# i=4, j=1
```

Comment: +1 - I agree that this is the correct answer to the OP's question. I've only added an answer myself b/c I hope to better highlight just how `next` and `break` differ.

Comment: Maybe just add a break indicator to break two loops